# Onclick Event UIView, while using multiple UIViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, events, uiview, onclick

I am new in IOS Dev, was searching onclick event for UIView and i found this code that worked perfectly. But it doesnt call specific UIView as i am using multiple UIViews and want  to add event on all of them separately  while this code calls handleSingleTap onclick of either UIView. plz help..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
}
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:[recognizer.view superview]];

NSLog(@"Clicked");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `UITapGestureRecognizer` and add it to the views you want it to be clicked.
You can also set up tag property on each view to find out which view was clicked.

For example:

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap1 =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    view1.tag = 1;
    [view1 addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap1];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap2 =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    view2.tag = 2;
    [view2 addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap2];
    //..and so on

    - (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
        UIView *viewClicked = recognizer.view;

        NSLog(@"Clicked: %d", viewClicked.tag);
    }
```

The other solution is add one gesture recogniser to the main view (the view which hold the others view, something as you posted) and in `handleSingleTap`: method check if the point is inside the view:

```
BOOL isPointInsideView1 = [view1 pointInside:location withEvent:nil];
BOOL isPointInsideView2 = [view1 pointInside:location withEvent:nil];
```

But ic can failed when one view override another.

Comment: Thanks that is working like a charm, just one problem in my program i have 3 UIViews (mover, flipper, grower) right now and its working for flipper and grower but not for mover... is there any problem in my mover View or something else?